# Mysql rows from one table moved and merged into named columns

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have the following data

```
drop table if exists states;
create table states (id integer, state varchar(100), content varchar(100));
insert into states (id, state, content) values (1, 'soc', '73');
insert into states (id, state, content) values (2, 'range', '412');
insert into states (id, state, content) values (3, 'range', '410');
insert into states (id, state, content) values (3, 'soc', '71');
insert into states (id, state, content) values (5, 'range', '405');
```

using the following statements

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN state = 'range' THEN content ELSE null END AS 'range',
       CASE WHEN state = 'soc' THEN content ELSE null END AS 'soc'
FROM states;
```

the result is

| id | range | soc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 73 |
| 2 | 412 |  |
| 3 | 410 |  |
| 3 |  | 71 |
| 5 | 405 |  |

but i would like to have the two lines with the id 3 merged into one row

| id | range | soc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 73 |
| 2 | 412 |  |
| 3 | 410 | 71 |
| 5 | 405 |  |

What must be changed to achieve the wanted result?

Comment: `GROUP BY id` and `MAX(CASE ..)` (or `MIN()`).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, but might i ask you to give a more detailed answer how those statements should be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT id,
>        CASE WHEN state = 'range' THEN content ELSE null END AS 'range',
>        CASE WHEN state = 'soc' THEN content ELSE null END AS 'soc'
> FROM states;
> ```
>
> | id | range | soc |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | *null* | 73 |
> | 2 | 412 | *null* |
> | 3 | 410 | *null* |
> | 3 | *null* | 71 |
> | 5 | 405 | *null* |

> ```
> SELECT id,
>        MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'range' THEN content END) AS 'range',
>        MAX(CASE WHEN state = 'soc' THEN content END) AS 'soc'
> FROM states
> GROUP BY id;
> ```
>
> | id | range | soc |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | *null* | 73 |
> | 2 | 412 | *null* |
> | 3 | 410 | 71 |
> | 5 | 405 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f5c6e4ad7e00dddfa4ef52374252169)*